# How to Force MS Teams Mobile Client to open Teams App in Chat Pane and not StaticTab?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

We have a Teams App with a bot and static web tab.  When a Microsoft Teams Desktop client user initially interacts with the app, by search or clicking on the pinned icon, or launching from recent conversations, the focus is on the Chat Pane/tab.  This is as expected.

However, when the Microsoft Teams Mobile Clients (IOS, Android) open the same Teams App from the list of Apps, the Teams app initially opens with focus on the StaticTab (and not on the Chat tab as in case of desktop client)

Is there a way to force the Teams Mobile clients to open the Teams App with focus on the chat pane?

Is this a know issue/bug with the Teams Mobile clients?

p.s.

The newer versions of the Teams manifest.json allow for reordering of the tabs/panes of a Teams App containing bot, files, statictabs.  This question is not related to that.  The order of tabs seems to have no difference in the Mobile client behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In Teams mobile client if the personal app has bot and tabs, the bot icon will display at header as shown in below image and it is by design. Currently there is  no option to open chat as default for custom tab and bot app.

[image]

Microsoft will always focus on customer’s feedback and experience, some new features would be added to the services based on customers' feedback in the future, we also recommend you give your new idea in Teams UserVoice [here](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/) if this needs to be consider as a future request.

Comment: This seems more like a bug, rather than a feature.  The desktop client honors the ordering of the tabs specified in the manifest, and the mobile clients do not. The mobile client is inconsistent.